# Why does the DatastoreInputReader filters param supports only equality operators?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I'm trying to process only events occurred after a specific date. In order to achieve that I tried to pass the **filters** param (mapper_params) using a greater than operator. However I got the following error: "Only equality filters are supported".

Here is how my run method looks like:

```
 def run(self, action, occurred_after):
    output = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
                "word_count",
                "main.word_count_map",
                "main.word_count_reduce",
                "mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader",
                "mapreduce.output_writers.FileOutputWriter",
                mapper_params={
                    "entity_kind": 'models.Event',
                    "filters": [("action", "=", action),
                    ("occurred_on", ">", occurred_after )]
                },
                reducer_params={
                    "filesystem": "gs",
                    "gs_bucket_name": "mybucket/mapreduce_output",
                    "mime_type": "text/plain",
                    "output_sharding": "input"
                },
                shards=1)
```

Does anyone know why only the "=" operator is supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapReduce internally uses an inequality filter on the KEY of the entity to split the database into small chunks of entities.

First it queries on a [secret property](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/ScatterPropertyImplementation) that is only present on a small subset of entities (once every 128 on average -- 0.78% chance), then queries entities between 2 sequential entities (between entity x and entity x+128 ), then runs your mapper function on each entity in that list(for each x, x+128 group it creates a task)